# Looking for overall review on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloud, mapreduce, hdfs

I am looking for some performance review on Hadoop (300-600 boxes cluster, commodity hardware), especially on the following aspects:

1. High concurrent read & write
2. Web crawling
3. Mapreduce, parallel computing
4. Inverted index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a specific question, maybe that is why nobody answered until now. Performance on 3-600 nodes cluster can be best analyzed with benchmarks.

However, I found some really interesting articles regarding Hadoop and its implementations in production:

- [Hadoop Architecture and its Usage at Facebook](http://borthakur.com/ftp/hadoopmicrosoft.pdf)
- [How Rackspace Now Uses MapReduce And Hadoop To Query Terabytes Of Data](http://highscalability.com/blog/2008/1/30/how-rackspace-now-uses-mapreduce-and-hadoop-to-query-terabyt.html)
- Some benchmarks are found in the article [Hadoop Sorts a Petabyte in 16.25 Hours and a Terabyte in 62 Seconds](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2009/05/hadoop_sorts_a_petabyte_in_162/)
- Also, a really interesting [blog related to Hadoop](http://hadoopblog.blogspot.com/)
- Another article related to facebook and hadoop is [Hive - A Petabyte Scale Data Warehouse using Hadoop](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=89508453919)

I hope those links will get you started and give you all the info you need.